# problem with reindex more than 500,000 SKU

Tags: magento-1.9

My magento website installed multi-warehouse extension. The concept of this extension is generating all product separate for each warehouse. and this make my db is very big. so far I check my database more than 500,000 product sku generated.

Problem is when I reindex, it alway error even I use SSH command. these 2 table I got a problem when reindex:

- catalog_product_attribute
- catalog_product_price

I already upgrade server to cloud but it may not enough. I found this extension:
https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-asynchronous-reindex.html

but not sure it work or not. Anyone who had experience on this extension and try with huge database pls recommend.

Thank so much

Comment: What is the problem specifically?

Comment: something about "timeout exceeded"

Comment: Please try increasing PHP Memory Limit of your server.

Comment: Ok i will try that. So it mean i no need to use extra extension right ? Magento default can handle it.

Comment: Max execution is probably more relevant @RahulKumarDas

Answer (score 0):

We use the async index extension and it works. But you have to experiment with the config options to find the best way for you.

In addition the extension can not handle catalog url indexer for us. We do it on a different server. We have 200.000 SKUs.

BTW: I think Magento and more than 100.000 SKUs is always pain.